# Why would an iOS app act differently on two different devices?

Tags: ios, memory-management, crash

If you were developing an iOS app using Xcode and were testing it on different devices, is there any reason as to why it would act differently given that the devices are the same model and have the same software version?

For example, I'd recently been working on an app. A clean build of that app were put on two different iPhone5s. (Same software version)

However while running on one of the phones I'd get a memory deallocation error similar to the following:

`*** -[CFString release]: message sent to deallocated instance`

Where as on the other device, no such error would appear.

Are there any obvious reasons as to why this might be the case for any app?

Comment: Which string was released? Post code so we can understand better.

Comment: Part of the problem is, I don't actually know where this is occurring or where the string is being released. It's very strange.

Comment: Have you tried setting a breakpoint on all exceptions?

Comment: Are your build settings (i.e. optimization level) the same for both builds? I have experienced something similar when compiling with ARC enabled and autoreleased objects and optimization cranked up..

Comment: Yeah I've tried stepping through the code using breakpoints etc.. I just have no clue as to go about debugging this issue.

Comment: @JimmyRowntree Are you compiling with ARC enabled?

Comment: The build settings are identical when running on each of the devices yes.

Comment: ARC is not enabled no.

Comment: Enable ARC and many of your memory management problems will instantly go away. Xcode even has a nice button to convert your existing code to ARC now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code probably isn't acting differently on the different devices. The problem most likely exists on all your devices, but will only cause a problem in certain circumstances. You can not predict when objects in the autorelease pool get deallocated, but you can be sure that it's not always going to be with the same timing. Running on different devices, timing of the draining of the autorelease pool can be different due to other background processes, memory usage, etc.

The deallocation error that you are seeing is most likely due to a `release` call you do on an autoreleased object, that you did not call `retain` on yourself. Check you code for objects that your create without an `init` call, but where you are calling `release` on. Also, try running your code in Instruments with enable Zombie Objects to see if you can find the `NSString` object that is causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your String is being under-retained or released.This problem occurs when you are trying to access the deallocated object. May be your string get released before you accessing it.I've face this problem.

Run your app in Instruments using the Zombies template. That will show you what object had the memory issue, and will let you see the entire retain/release history of that object. That should point you in the right direction.

For Zombies enable

```
option+cmnd+r
```

and then select `Enable Zombie Objects` and then `Run`.

Comment: An issue with that is that using the simulator to run the app won't trigger this error for some reason. Can I use the Zombies templates while running the app on an actual device? I've never done that before.

Comment: Yes you can enable if you have developer provisioning.

Comment: Would I just have to attach it to a specific process in order to do that?

Comment: can we talk tomorrow.Coz time to over so need to gonna sorry for inconvience.

Comment: Have you tried simulating memory warnings on the simulator?  It's under the Hardware menu.  This usually forces any memory issues that are around.